# How to keep a smooth surface with sharp edges when subdiv applied?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to make the following object:

[image]

Here's a block out of the object for reference. I also shared my blender file below if you want a closer look.

[image]

[image]

When I applied the subdiv modifier to the block out, the edges of the extruded faces are no longer sharp.

[image]

I added loop edges to maintain the sharp edges but it introduces pinches on some surfaces.
[image]

[image]

I tried changing my topology so the loop edges don't go around my entire object adding unncessary edges but still no luck.

[image]

[image]

I also tried creases, mark sharp, other edge flow topology and none of them solve the issue. Anyone knows what else I can do to keep a smooth surface with sharp edges when subdiv applied?

**UPDATE**

Current result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create this topology:

[image]

Bevel it:

[image]

Give it *Array*, *Simple Deform* and *Subdivision Surface* modifiers:

[image]

Also give it a *Lattice* modifier if you want to make it narrow at its top and bottom:

[image]

Comment: Woah, they are perfectly smooth and sharp just as I want! I'm trying to recreate your steps but I'm having trouble understand step one. Could you clarify with a few more steps on how you create that shape and topology? I attached a screenshot of what I think you did in the first step (at the bottom of my post). Please check it out and let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can begin with this topology then bevel, I hope it's more clear

Comment: I seem to have the topology down but I can't get the bevel to look like yours. I took a screenshot of the edges I think you beveled. Mind elaborating on that part?

Comment: nothing complicated here, you need to model the first mesh, select the edges and bevel, then dissolve some edges, join some others, etc

Comment: Unfortunately I have a lack of understanding of these basic things as I'm still learning so any additional details/explanation would be very helpful to me. Anyhow, I managed to get to your result but I notice there's a bubble effect (see my post) and I also see it in yours. Were you able to resolve that?

Comment: Put a Weld modifier before the Subdivision Surface modifier so that the last and first vertices merge